Invalid Webhook Token error after few hours of auto sending images
I was trying to make a slash command for my discord bot which will automatically send 1 image from e621 for example every one minute. It works for a hour or two. But then throws an error and the bot crashes.
here is the error:
/home/****/Desktop/discorde6Bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:687
throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
^

DiscordAPIError[50027]: Invalid Webhook Token
at handleErrors (/home//****//Desktop/discorde6Bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:687:13)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (/home/****/Desktop/discorde6Bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1072:23)
at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/home/****/Desktop/discorde6Bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:913:14)
at async _REST.request (/home/****/Desktop/discorde6Bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1218:22)
at async InteractionWebhook.send (/home/****/Desktop/discorde6Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Webhook.js:222:15)
at async Timeout.spamLoop [as _onTimeout] (/home/****/Desktop/discorde6Bot/commands/e621spam.js:120:11) {
requestBody: {
files: [],
json: {
content: 'Something went wrong. Sorry',
tts: false,
nonce: undefined,
embeds: undefined,
components: undefined,
username: undefined,
avatar_url: undefined,
allowed_mentions: undefined,
flags: undefined,
message_reference: undefined,
attachments: undefined,
sticker_ids: undefined,
thread_name: undefined
}
},
rawError: { message: 'Invalid Webhook Token', code: 50027 },
code: 50027,
status: 401,
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/1082024195938062437/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTIzNjQzODg0Njk0MjQ3ODQxNzp4QmVsa09QWUVZN0VrSkRUWHpHRVZQSzZZd2k1cUt5dzVDdENrT0JPQThkTUdlWTgza2hXdkhwalJIQWdkVHlaRkNsNlhaVjdDd2FzU0l3dmE1SHN0cURJdFdhSTFaTlAxMnFpc2JiTWsycFlRUWM4ZXVZd21XOEpyckdVSTRsdA?wait=true'
}

here is the code:
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const axios = require('axios');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const activeSpams = new Map(); // Map to store active spams

function randomPicUrl(response, usedIndices) {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * response.data.posts.length);
  let post;

  if (usedIndices.includes(randomIndex)) {
    return randomPicUrl(response, usedIndices);
  } else {
    post = response.data.posts[randomIndex];
    usedIndices.push(randomIndex);
    return post.file.url;
  }
}

function containsBlacklistedTags(tags, blacklist) {
  for (const tag of tags) {
    let checkTagElem = tag.split(' ');
    for (const e of checkTagElem) {
      if (blacklist.includes(e.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('e621spam')
    .setDescription('Start or stop sending random images from e621 with the given tags')
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('action')
        .setDescription('Start or stop spamming')
        .setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('tags')
        .setDescription('Tags to search for')
        .setRequired(false))
    .addIntegerOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('interval')
        .setDescription('Interval between sending images (in minutes)')
        .setRequired(false)),

  async execute(interaction) {
    const action = interaction.options.getString('action');
    const tags = interaction.options.getString('tags')?.split(',') || [];
    const interval = interaction.options.getInteger('interval');

    const guildId = interaction.guildId;
    const channelId = interaction.channelId;
    const spamKey = `${guildId}-${channelId}`;

    if (action === 'start') {
      if (activeSpams.has(spamKey)) {
        await interaction.reply({ content: "There's already an active e621spam in this channel.", ephemeral: true });
        return;
      }

      const spamLoop = async () => {
        const blacklist = ['de*****', 'go***', 'tent****', 'fa***', 'sc***', 'animated', 'type:mp4', 'type:webm'];
        const e621ApiUrl = "https://e621.net/posts.json?tags=order:random " + tags;

        console.log(`Constructed URL: ${e621ApiUrl}`);

        try {
          if (!interaction.channel.nsfw) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: "This command can only be used in NSFW channels." });
            clearInterval(activeSpams.get(spamKey));
            activeSpams.delete(spamKey);
            return;
          }

          if (containsBlacklistedTags(tags, blacklist)) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: "Content contains blacklisted tags." });
            clearInterval(activeSpams.get(spamKey));
            activeSpams.delete(spamKey);
            return;
          }

          const response = await axios.get(e621ApiUrl, {
            headers: { "User-Agent": "Discord Bot (************ on 621)" },
            maxContentLength: 8 * 1024 * 1024, // Limiting max content length to 8MB
          });

          console.log(response.data.posts.length);

          const usedIndices = [];
          const imageUrl = randomPicUrl(response, usedIndices);

          if (imageUrl === null) {
            return;
          }

          // Check file size before sending
          const contentLength = response.headers['content-length'];
          if (contentLength && parseInt(contentLength) > 8 * 1024 * 1024) {
            console.log("File size is too big! Retrying...");
            return;
          }

          // Create an embed message
          const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Random Image from e621')
            .setDescription(`[View Image](${imageUrl})`)
            .setImage(imageUrl)
            .setColor('#0099ff');

          // Send the embed message
          await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

        } catch (e) {
          await interaction.followUp("Something went wrong. Sorry");
          console.log(e);
          clearInterval(activeSpams.get(spamKey));
          activeSpams.delete(spamKey);
        }
      };

      // Start the spam loop
      const spamInterval = setInterval(spamLoop, interval * 60 * 1000); // Convert minutes to milliseconds

      activeSpams.set(spamKey, spamInterval);
      await interaction.reply({ content: "e621spam started!", ephemeral: true });

    } else if (action === 'stop') {
      if (!activeSpams.has(spamKey)) {
        await interaction.reply({ content: "There's no active e621spam in this channel.", ephemeral: true });
        return;
      }

      clearInterval(activeSpams.get(spamKey));
      activeSpams.delete(spamKey);
      await interaction.reply({ content: "e621spam stopped!", ephemeral: true });
    }
  },
};



Tried to make it retry and  make a new webhook token which didnt help at all. im expecting it to keep sending forever until i  use a command for it to stop

Discord moderates the content of an incoming webhooks and may revoke the webhook token due to Spam & Flood, NSFW content not in a appropriate channel, or hitting 429 err code too often.
Make sure your channel setting "Age-Restricted Channel" is enabled.

I made a check if the command is used in age restricted channel. The command doesn't work if I run it in any other channel that doesn't have age restriction enabled

Have you tried to create a new webhook? https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/1082024195938062437/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTIzNjQzODg0Njk0MjQ3ODQxNzp4QmVsa09QWUVZN0VrSkRUWHpHRVZQSzZZd2k1cUt5dzVDdENrT0JPQThkTUdlWTgza2hXdkhwalJIQWdkVHlaRkNsNlhaVjdDd2FzU0l3dmE1SHN0cURJdFdhSTFaTlAxMnFpc2JiTWsycFlRUWM4ZXVZd21XOEpyckdVSTRsdA?wait=true seems to be invalid. Are webhooks created by the bot? If so, make sure the bot doesn't create a new webhook every time it posts an embed, instead it's fetches for existing webhooks and uses them to post content.
